# How to get the right foreign-key when importing from a CSV

Tags: .net, automapper, csvhelper

I'm migrating an application from Access to a cloud-based solution.
This access file has no relation defined and I've trouble importing data. For simplicity, I've exported the tables as CSV and tried to import with [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Consider this simple scenario

`Book_ID;escription;BookType`

Now in my csv I've got

1;A plague tale;Drama
2;Flowers and how to kill them;floriculture

I've created a BookType class, mapped to Table with EF Core with the form

`[PK,Identity] GUID,Description`

And the Book class as

`[PK,Identity] GUID,BookDescription,[FK to BookType] FK_BookType`

I don't know (and even don't know if it's possible) how to fill the relation. I mean

I can import the distinct values from CSV of BookType and insert them into the BookType table
I don't know when I import the Books how to tell instead of the value put the Guid taken from the BookType.

I'm using ABP.io as Framework, so I've AutoMapper and the dependency injection, but I think I can't resolve the IRespository inside the Book's mapper.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your `Books` CSV has the `BookType.Description` instead of the `BookType.GUID` and that is your problem right?

Comment: yes, since in this freak access DB, they haven't used foreign keys so I've the description and no book type table.. but I want to make thinks right

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: yes as I wrote, EF Core

Comment: Try using `Alternate Keys` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use [EF Core Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys). Your `DbContext` could look like this (change Id's from `int` to `GUID` for your scenario):

```cs
internal class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookType> BookTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasOne(book => book.BookType)
            .WithMany(bookType => bookType.Books)
            .HasForeignKey(book => book.BookTypeDescription)
            .HasPrincipalKey(bookType => bookType.Description);
    }
}

public class BookType
{
    public int BookTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string BookTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public BookType BookType { get; set; }
}
```

Now if you map `Description` from CSV to `Book.BookTypeDescription` EF Core should handle everything correctly.

[More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#principal-key) documentation about Principal key.

### Edit:

Another option is to load the CSV, find the distinct book type descriptions using LINQ and insert them to the `BookType` table so that you get Id's. Then manually map each book type description to book type id.

Example code:

```cs
void ImportFromCsv()
{
    IEnumerable<BookCsv> booksFromCsv = LoadDataFromCsv();
    
    // get distinct book types
    List<BookType> bookTypes = booksFromCsv
       .GroupBy(b => b.Description)
       .Select(g => g.First())
       .ToList();

    _dbContext.BookTypes.AddRange(bookTypes);

    // ef core will populate the BookType.Id's here
    _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();    
      
    // manually map each book type description to book type id
    foreach(var bookCsv in booksFromCsv)
    {
        var bookType = bookTypes.First(b => b.Description = bookCsv.Description);
        bookCsv.BookTypeId = bookType.Id;
    }
    
    var books = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Book>>(booksFromCsv);
}
```

Where the entities would look like this:

```cs
public class BookType
{
    public int BookTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int BookTypeId { get; set; }
    public BookType BookType { get; set; }
}
```

And the `BookCsv` class:

```cs
public class BookCsv
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int BookTypeId { get; set; } // we will populate manually after inserting book types to databases
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for this reply, but in this way I need to have a BookTypeDescription in the Book model and it's not correct from my point of view

Comment: Added another option to my answer that might help.